# ScrollViewer inside ComboBox popup overflows right back from the start when using touch

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, touch, scrollviewer

I have a ScrollViewer nested inside of Popup of a ComboBox. I believe it is a standard design. Even without any **DependencyProperties** set, this ScrollViewer has a peculiar behavior when scrolled with a touch gesture.

When I use touch & I reach the end of the ComboBoxItems inside aforementioned popup, ScrollBar moves back to the start of the popup and continues scrolling. Like that:
[image]

I've come to believe this is a standard behavior. As you can see, English is the first language in the list, Polish & Bulgarian come in as the last languages of the list. Can you please tell me what is the name of that behavior? Can it be turned off?

I would post the ComboBox style, but I don't think it matters, because its structure largely matches the default style from: *C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\10.0.18362.0\Generic\generic.html*

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I use touch & I reach the end of the ComboBoxItems inside aforementioned popup, ScrollBar moves back to the start of the popup and continues scrolling

It's by-design within `ComboBox` control for touch model. `ComboBox` use [`CarouselPanel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.CarouselPanel?view=winrt-18362) as ItemsPanel by default. It will make the list  loop scroll. If you want to disable this feature, please replace `CarouselPanel` with `StackPanel`.

```
<ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
   <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
   </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
```